# Uderstanding *args and **kwargs

Tags: python, args, keyword-argument

I'm trying to get used to using *args and **kwargs  in python functions but I have got hard time with it.

For example:

```
def foo(a, b, *args):
   print(a)
   print(b)
   if args1 == True:
      print(args2)
   else:
      print(a+args1)
```

so if I run it as

```
foo('one','two')
```

I'm expecting it to print me `'one'` and `'two'`,
but if I run

```
foo('one','two',True,'three')
```

I want to get `'one'`, `'two'` and `'three'`,
and as

```
foo('one','two','three')
```

I want to get `'one','two', 'onethree'`

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

**args**

definition:

```
def foo1(a, b, *args):
   print(a)
   print(b)
   if args:
      for arg in args:
          print(arg)
```

usage:

```
foo1(1, 2, 3, 4)
foo1(1, 2, *[3, 4])
```

**kwargs**

definition:

```
def foo2(a, b, **kwargs):
   print(a)
   print(b)
   if kwargs:
      for k, v in kwargs.items():
          print(f'{k}: {v}')
```

usage:

```
foo2(1, 2, c=3, d=4)
foo2(1, 2, **{'c':3, 'd':4})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  def foo(a, b, *args):
    print(a)
    print(b)
    if args and args[0]==True:
        print(args[0])
    else:
        print(a+args[0])

foo('one','two','three')

one
two
onethree
```

Comment: 1. This will crash if no args are passed. 2. Don't spoon feed people - like in the saying, don't give them a fish, teach them how to catch fish.